# Intellij UML diagram does not show one to many relationships

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to follow http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/uml_class_diagram.html I have a few classes so when I do Ctrl + Alt + U I only see all classes and just Extends relationships.

Please note that I have set the "Diagrams" options in my settings to show one to many etc.

- I do not see One to One, One to Many relationships at all ? I have used JPA OneToOne Annotations and they dont turn up at all?
- Pressing Ctrl Shift F12 does not do anything?

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 3):

Actually it appears there is a "Show Dependencies" icon. Toggling that and toggling it again actually shows my relationships one to one, one to many etc

Answer (score 0):

In order to see these relationships you have to right click in the diagram and select "Show Edge Labels".

[image: Selected Show Edge Labels in Intelij]

This works in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1 (Ultimate Edition), April 30, 2021

Answer (score 0):

Using 9th icon from left side of image ,we can show relationships between classes.
[image]

> This option is only available in Intelij ultimate edition.